# Having Multiple buildpacks in cloudfoundry

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I need to specify multiple buildpacks in my springboot application.

I have created a file `multi-buildpack.yml` in the root dir of my application where i have specified the 2 buildpacks.

```
multi-buildpack.yml File

buildpacks:
- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack
- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack
```

But i am getting the below error while pushing my app:

> **ERROR** A multi-buildpack.yml file must be provided at your app root to use this buildpack.

Can anyone please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to ensure that you are using the cf CLI v6.38 or later:

```
$ cf version
```

To push your app with multiple buildpacks, specify each buildpack with a -b flag:

```
$ cf push YOUR-APP -b BUILDPACK-NAME-1 -b BUILDPACK-NAME-2 ... -b FINAL-BUILDPACK-NAME
```

The last buildpack you specify is the final buildpack, which can modify the launch environment and set the start command.

To see a list of available buildpacks, run `cf buildpacks`

More: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html

Comment: php buildpack and python buidpack combination is not working. throwing error

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're on an older version of CloudFoundry, you shouldn't use the multi-buildpack buildpack anymore.  True multi-buildpack support is available in the platform.  Use that instead.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html

This is currently a two step process due to some limitations with the current `cf` cli:

1. `cf push YOUR-APP --no-start -b binary_buildpack`
2. `cf v3-push YOUR-APP -b BUILDPACK-NAME-1 -b BUILDPACK-NAME-2`

That should go away at some point in the future and be just one command.

If you really want to use the multi-buildpack buildpack, double check the location of the multi-buildpack.yml file and the format of it.  You can compare to one of the fixture tests [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/multi-buildpack/tree/master/fixtures/go_calls_python).  Maybe even run one of the fixture tests to get a baseline test that works (or at least, should work).

Hope that helps!